# Would like to run CLIENT LIST from my redis-db client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have a redis-db client in my Heroku app. I would like to run the `CLIENT LIST` command (and a couple of other commands such as `COMMAND GET`). How could I achieve this? I have tried

```
$redis.eval('CLIENT LIST')
$redis.exec('CLIENT LIST')
```

but no dice. How would I achieve this?

Comment: The `eval` method probably maps to Redis` [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval) that's used for running server-side Lua scripts, whereas the `exec` method invokes the [EXEC](http://redis.io/commands/exec) command that's used to execute a Redis transaction. Both are not designed to run "raw" Redis commands such as the ones you're attempting to invoke. Which RoR Redis client are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [method_missing](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L2519) function:

```
$redis.method_missing("client", "list")
```

Comment: I use Resque 1.x and was able to get an array of clients using this command `Resque.redis.redis.method_missing(:client, :list).split("\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

`redis.call(['client', 'list'])` although it gives just plain, unfiltered output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `method_missing` gives me a deprecation warning.

Instead, using the `redis-3.2.1` gem, you can do:

`Resque.redis.client.call(['client','list'])`